# What is the real cause of burn-in effect on OLED(organic light emitting diode) displays and how can burn-in effect be solved?

Tags: organic-chemistry

[image]

In the picture above you can see how some logos have permanently burnt-in. I wonder if it has to do with the fact that the materials are "organic" as the name suggest, or because current oled displays use a combination of fluorescent and phosphorescent materials which causes the uneven aging.

"*In OLEDs using fluorescent organic molecules only, the decay of triplet excitons is quantum mechanically forbidden by selection rules, meaning that the lifetime of triplet excitons is long and phosphorescence is not readily observed. Hence it would be expected that in fluorescent OLEDs only the formation of singlet excitons results in the emission of useful radiation, placing a theoretical limit on the internal quantum efficiency (the percentage of excitons formed that result in emission of a photon) of 25%.[4]
However, phosphorescent OLEDs generate light from both triplet and singlet excitons, allowing the internal quantum efficiency of such devices to reach nearly 100%.[5]*"

Comment: "[O]rganic materials that make OLED TVs’ self-emissive displays could decay under prolonged exposure to static image elements," per https://www.whathifi.com/advice/oled-burn-in-should-you-be-worried-about-it-and-how-can-you-prevent-it . That is, actual chemical decomposition occurs from localized heating or other cause.

Comment: @DrMoishePippik The decay is usually photochemical. If there were localised heating, that would make it worse, but that isn't the primary cause.

Answer (score 3):

**The simple explanation is that some of the non-emissive pathways damage the emitting material**

There are several ways to turn electrical energy into light. Old monitors and TVs used phosphorescent minerals that glowed when hit by electron beams. They suffer burn-in if the same image is displayed for an extended period.

OLEDs use a variety of organic materials (often specialised polymers, but sometimes small organic molecules) which glow when an electrical current is applied across them. They suffer burn-in too.

Some screen types do not. LCD displays use liquid crystals to "filter" light from a backlight source. They don't (usually) suffer burn in.

Why are they different?

LCDs switch polarisation driven by very small voltages and the process is not a chemical reaction in any sense, but is driven by small physical changes in how the liquid crystals are arranged in the liquid crystal layer. The energies involved are tiny and the rearrangement effectively completely reversible so no lasting changes occur even when the same image is held for a long time.

But, in the other two cases, there is a *photochemical* reaction occurring with much higher energies involved. This is more obvious in a CRT display driven by high-speed electrons hitting a phosphor. The energies are significant. What happens is that electrons in the phosphor structure are bounced to much higher energy levels and then emit light when they decay back to the ground state. But these reactions are never 100% perfect, and there may be a very small probability that, instead of simply falling back to the ground state and emitting light, a different reaction pathway disrupts the structure of the phosphor, damaging its future ability to emit the right colour of light. Even when these alternative pathways are very improbable, they can eventually (because they may be irreversible) damage the phosphor, yielding a burnt-in image in the parts of the screen that see the most action.

Exactly the same problem occurs in OLEDs but at lower energies (but then OLED materials are usually a lot more fragile than CRT phosphors). The photochemical reactions are driven by the injection of electrons or holes into the materials, bouncing some of the electrons in the material into higher energy levels which then decay, emitting light. But, again, the pathway the leads to the emission of light is not exactly 100% efficient, and the small number of alternative paths available to the excited molecules are often damaging to the molecular structure and slowly reduce its ability to emit the right wavelength of light. That the energy involved matters is illustrated by the observation that it is much harder to make good blue OLEDs (higher energy light=more energy required to excite the electrons) than red OLEDs (lower energy light...)

The bottom line is that the light emission from CRT phosphors or OLED compounds is a photochemical process and they are never perfectly 100% efficient, and the side reactions eventually damage the material.

Fixing the problem *perfectly* is impossible. But finding better materials (with better quantum efficiency or fewer side reactions) is an important task. Of course, other strategies are also possible. Screen savers were invented when CRT computer displays were common and work to prevent the same image being displayed for extended periods, reducing the scale of burn-in. Many OLED manufacturers have built in similar ideas to the software running their monitors and TVs. A common strategy is to regularly shift the image by a few (not very noticeable) pixels so the same pixel does not always see the same part of the image.

I suspect both the software and the choice of OLED materials have led to big improvements in the last decade as the burn-in problem seems much less severe now than it used to be.

Comment: Since light emission from OLED compounds is a "photochemical process" which is why burn-in occurs, does the same apply for microled displays which instead use inorganic leds made from gallium?

Comment: @AquaNeon it is certainly *possible* that micro LEDs will see similar effects. And there is little evidence that other LED-based displays see the effect, possibly because their simpler solid-state structures don't have so many opportunities for side-reactions. It might be a matter of degree where the effect is small enough not to be noticable in normal lifetimes.